# How to put transitions on hover over image

Tags: html, image, css

So far i have this

```
<img src="1.png" onmouseover="this.src='hover1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='1.png'" class="HomePortfolioLeft image1" />
```

The original image will change into another image while hovering, and i have achieved this.
But the problem is that it just snaps to the other image on hover and it is really unpleasent.
To appeal to my designers side and to keep the client happy, i want to put a transitions between the images. ( when hovered, a transition and then the next image)
How can i do this.

> *All help is appreciated. Thank you for your effort :D.*

Comment: You will need 2 containers, via CSS, transition or animation, are calculated from values that can be divided. src.value can only switch from one to another, no way to blend 2 different source / file.What kind of transition are you looking for ? a slide could be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without javascript using background-image as a preloader of second image.

**LIMITS :**

1. img has to be a known size.
2. not as many effects possible as in between 2 elements.

**HOW does it work.**

using the box-model, you can set to 0 width and height switching values to padding to keep at every step of transition the same outer size.

here some examples : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Joqzp/

shrink image down to middle would be :

```
img {
 /* known size */
    height:80px;
    width:150px;
 /* size to switch to padding */
    padding:0;
 /* preloaded image to switch to ,visually */
    background-image:url(image2.jpg);    
    /* transition timing */
    transition:0.5s;
}
img:hover {
 /* size */
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
 /* padding to resize the box and show background-image*/
    padding:40px 75px;
 /* timing*/
    transition:0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for the long reply but i had some internet problems, so i couldn't see any answers . But really clever. I didnt think of that

Comment: I want the image transition to be a fade out or something on thoses lines. How can i achieve this?

Comment: added to demo one boxe, image shows and expand from center (reverse effect one in post, just switch :hover attribute) , i'll had more in a few days

Comment: i added one extra effect in the test i linked (last one), wich is an opposite to the piece pf code up here in the post. Best might be that you describe what you try to do. and if your images are hold in a link or any other tag, it would be very usefull to know as well :)

Comment: Ok. So i am making a gallery. When visitors hover on the image, it would flip and show another .png (this image would the the same image as before, but would be with a green tint, and frost glass kind effect with a short four word despcription of what the image is, a caption if you will.
what i want is to have the flip transition between the two images. Like flipping a post card to the other side. I tried many ways, but i couldnt achieve this. My Question is how can i do this.

Comment: The code is as it is. That is the whole section, part of the image gallery where the images are, right up in the code i provided. No links, background images or anything else . 
Is this useful GCyrillus :)

Comment: yes it is , you should update your question , cause here  a bit more than just an image tag is involved , caption needs to come from somewhere.  Or it  is in a data attribute of image, and javadcript build itself html structure needed to flip imageS and show text, or html structure is already there : minimal could be : `<figure><img><figcaption>text</figaption></figure>`.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1jeW4p5    ,    
http://bit.ly/1lrwPSV
these are both the images.
http://bit.ly/1gy7FPH
in the this link you can see a 3d image flip. This is what i want. But instead of the caption text, i want the second image, with the green tint and words, to be there.
So When the user hovers, the image flips, and after flipping, it shows the second image. User take mouse away, it flips back showing the original image. Do you understand it now?

Comment: i see , what have you tried yourself so far ?  what you can do via js  is to set a time out so image switch halfway of animation, or look at flip cards effects , else use one of the container itself to get image in bg (so it is already loaded) basicly : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cHirI  ... google drive image are broken

Comment: The flip animations are not working. There is absolutely no animations involved. just pictures with text and green tint. I want the image to be originally effect free, flip, next image, this time this image would have these tint and text.

Comment: i want to see what you tried so far , thanks and please edit your question . like as key word flip-3d card effect :)

Comment: i havent got far, all i got is an img tag with a src linking to the image. Frankly i am clueless as to what to do here. To the full extent of my HTML, CSS or javascript knowledge, i dont know how to do this. I only know basic Js too. This is also my first major project.

Comment: oki, to have 3d you need to use transform-3d:preserve-3d; in body , and then set a perspective from the container you want it to be calcuated . transform:scale(); is not adapted to 3d , but rotate does : here last pen updated with 3 d , rotate and wrapping a few images within a div to set perspective from there : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wDKlu/ you will need to read a few tutorials to get confident with CSS and transform rules.

Comment: The flip animations are not playing on hover, and none of those are working

Comment: add prefix or use the built in option to add them via js . (option added , linked update) . if you dev , never forget to test with different browsers , and be curious about inline tools :) it worked witout prefix in FF28 . i understand it's a lot to get at once if you are beginner , but answers are mainly hints to advice you in a way or another

Answer (score 0):

This would help u.. [How to Hover over image](http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/)

Comment: Wrong answer. OP wants the image src to swap.